# Assigning a vm for azure pipline task rather than creating a new vm's for each run

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines, devops

As a beginner of DevOps, I would like to know how to use one VM for azure pipeline runs. When starting the run of the azure pipeline task it always gives a fresh VM from azure.
For caching and file saving purposes, I want to use a reserved VM for pipeline run.
Appreciate your suggestions and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the pic, In the Azure DevOps, we could run the pipeline via Hosted agent and Self-Host agent.

Azure Pipelines provides a pre-defined agent pool named **Azure Pipelines**, this is hosted agent and each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use.

[image]

> For caching and file saving purposes, I want to use a reserved VM for pipeline run.

We could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to install the self-hosted agent, it will save the cache.

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Hi @IOTTest, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: can i reserved one agent from the azure agent pool?

Comment: Hi @IOTTest, We cannot do this, I recommend that you do this via self-hosted agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a 'self hosted agent'. That would be your own VM, which you have total control over. I'm not sure whether this will be any cheaper than hosted agents.

I've used a self-hosted agent a while ago, and saved some money booting the VM only when needed. After a while it would shutdown again.

Source: [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped you please provide it with upvotes / mark it as answer. That way it's clear for everybody! Thank you.

Comment: can i reserved one agent from the azure agent pool?